# Selecting text using xpath when only preceding items have identifiers

Tags: html, xpath

I have code that follows the following format as below. I'm trying to use xpath to select the 2nd paragraph (eg the paragraph that starts: Assisted living is a great option for all walks of life...Given that the div and the paragraph have no easy identifiers, I tried:

```
//div[preceding-sibling::div[@id='w_29207']]/p[2]
```

I would think that the first portion //div....29207']] would select the div that is preceded by the  div with the id 29207. Then the /p[2] would pick he 2nd paragraph.

```
<div id="w_29207" class=" city short-description">
<div>
<p>
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Albuquerque, NM Assisted Living Facilities" />Choose from over 38 Assisted Living communities in Albuquerque, NM and 
<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">see
<meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="360 reviews "/>360 reviews with a
<meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.0 stars out of 5" />4.0 average rating.
<meta itemprop="description" content="Albuquerque attracts seniors looking for an active senior living experience. The city enjoys four distinct seasons with stunning winters and sunny summers. Seniors in Albuquerque find various cultural outlets and outdoor recreation including an active theater community, festivals, hiking and climbing. " /> We've helped 9,287 families in Albuquerque, NM where Assisted Living ranges from $</span><span itemprop='offerDetails' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/AggregateOffer'><span content='1,550' itemprop='lowPrice'>1,550</span> to $<span content='6,100' itemprop='highPrice'>6,100</span>.
<meta content='USD' itemprop='priceCurrency'>

</span></span></p>

<p>Assisted living is a great option for all walks of life. Whether you or a loved has experienced a life changing health diagnosis or you want to shed the burdens of home maintenance from your life, assisted living in Albuquerque could be the perfect match for you. Many seniors in Albuquerque have chosen to transition to assisted living so they can enjoy a sense of community with like-minded neighbors. Another perk of assisted living is for seniors that may need assistance with daily tasks such as, meal preparation, medication management, or help getting to appointments.
</p>
```

Comment: I please come back and accept the correct of these and make this question as solved...:)

Answer (score 0):

p[2] will work if p elements are sibling.

Some of the options:

```css
//*[contains(@class, 'city short-description')]/div/p[2]

//*[@class='city short-description']/div/p[2]

//div[contains(@class, 'city')]/div/p[2]

//div[contains(@id, 'w_')]/div/p[2]
```

If you need to return the text and not the element add an /text() after p[2]

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the second `<div>` is not a sibling of the `<div id="w_29207">`, it's a child of it (unless the HTML you posted is wrong). That's why `//div[preceding-sibling::div[@id='w_29207']]` doesn't select the second `<div>`.

Instead, you could use

```
//div[@id='w_29207']/div[1]/p[2]
```

or any of the options that @lauda mentioned, depending on how precise you have to be about the id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following `xpath` as well :-

```
//p[not(child::*)]
```

or

```
//p[ancestor::div[@id='w_29207']][2]
```

or

```
//div[@id='w_29207']/descendant::p[2]
```

or

```
//p[ancestor::div[@id='w_29207'] and not(child::*)]
```

Hope it helps..:)